# Retrofit 2 GET request without endpoints?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I would like to send a "GET" request without endpoints just whole url, but when I sending  my request it's doesnt works , I get just answer from my "onFailure" method.

This is my url:
http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll ( I have proved this url on Postman , and there I can get correct respond)

this is my Retrofit Client:

```
     private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll/";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(String url){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Here is Interface:

```
     @GET()
  Call<ServerResponse> showTheStations(@Url String url);
```

My respond method in MainActivity:

```
     public void retrofitRespond(){

    retrofitInterface = ApiUtil.getRetrofitInterface();

    retrofitInterface.showTheStations("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-
    api/rest/station/findAll").enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WENT WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

How can I do it correctly? I have read about dynamic url in Retrofit 2 , but I can't do it correctly.

Comment: can you post the error ...?

Comment: There is no error , I mean the method "public void onFailure" is catching my respond . I can't figure out, which response.code() I have

Comment: @Adam In onFailure(),to see error add Log.e(TAG, t.toString());

Comment: LOG FROM ONFAILURE -
 com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Do you understand something from this Exception , maybe i shouldn't use Retrofit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
@GET()
    Call<List<ServerResponse>> showTheStations(@Url String url);
```

And in MainActivity:

```
Call<List<ServerResponse>> call = retrofitInterface.showTheStations("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll/");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ServerResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ServerResponse>> call, Response<List<ServerResponse>> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, response.body().toString());

                List<ServerResponse> body = response.body();

                Log.i(TAG, body.get(0).getId()+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ServerResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I was trying this , but it doesn't help . I made already a lot of requests , but this one I cant find out.

Comment: @Adam i mean why not just use @GET("findAll")
Call<ServerResponse> showTheStations();

Comment: I have tried this solution but it doesn't work I got this exception in onFailure method "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"

Comment: @Adam See my updated Answer.It will works,I have try it myself

Comment: Yes , it works ! Awesome. Thanks for sacrificed your time :)